# jwplayer playlist: Hide/show listbar

Tags: javascript, jwplayer

I want two things with my jwplayer that I do not find any documentation on

1. I want to be able to hide and show the 'listbar' on mouse events (click) like the "watch later" feature on youtube.
2. I want my jwplayer to change the browser url when you click on a item in the list rather than load the new content in "the same player". Also this just like the "watch later" feature on youtube.

My code looks like this

```
jwplayer("videoplayer").setup({
    playlist: basehttp+"/playlist.php",
    listbar: {
        position: 'right',
        size: 320
    },
    skin: "bekle",
    width: "95%",
    aspectratio: "16:9"

});
```

And my playlist.php generates playlists like this

```
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:jwplayer="http://rss.jwpcdn.com/">
    <channel>    
        <item>
            <title>incredible video 1</title>
            <description>Description for video 1</description>
            <jwplayer:image>/assets/img1.jpg</jwplayer:image>
            <jwplayer:source file="/assets/vid1.mp4" />
        </item> 

        <item>
            <title>incredible video 2</title>
            <description>Description for video 2</description>
            <jwplayer:image>/assets/img2.jpg</jwplayer:image>
            <jwplayer:source file="/assets/vid2.mp4" />
        </item> 
    </channel>
</rss>
```

How do I modify my player to do this? Anyone have any similar experiences?

Comment: We do not really have events for #1. Regarding #2, this can be done with our related feature - http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/28858/displaying-related-videos, and instead of having it display in the same player, you can make them go to a link.